# Analyze app window doesn't show up in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm following this tutorial.
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

> Use the analyzer in Android Studio You can download the Android Size
> Analyzer plugin using the plugin marketplace in Android Studio, as
> shown in figure 1. To open the plugin marketplace and install the
> plugin, proceed as follows:
>
> Select File > Settings (or on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences.)
> Select the Plugins section in the left panel. Click the Marketplace
> tab. Search for the "Android Size Analyzer" plugin. Click the Install
> button for the analyzer plugin.
>
> Figure 1. The Android Size Analyzer plugin in the Marketplace tab.
>
> After you install the plugin, run a app size analysis on your current
> project by selecting Analyze > Analyze App Size from the menu bar.
> After analyzing your project, a tool window appears with
> recommendations on how to reduce the size of your app, as shown in
> figure 2

The problem is that the analyze app window never shows up why? After clicking on Analyze App Size

Answer (score 0):

> The Size Analyzer was an experimental project that is not actively
> supported by Google. Developers are free to fork and improve it under
> the terms of the Apache license.

https://github.com/android/size-analyzer